# Spark program throws exception

Tags: apache-spark, exception

I have the below spark program and I am running it in Windows (Eclipse/Maven).

```
public class LoadingJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder()
                         .appName("My First App in newer version of Spark")
                         .master("local")
                         .getOrCreate();
        ss.read()
          .json("G:\\users\\student.json").show();

    }

}
```

Below is the POM file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

After submitting the program, I am getting the following exception.
Can you please help to fix the exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$;
    at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.AllJobsPage.<init>(AllJobsPage.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.<init>(JobsTab.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2509)
    at
```

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:90 
   9)
        at

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:90 
   1)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at 
    org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:901)
        at spark.LoadingJson.main(LoadingJson.java:14)

Comment: Specifically mixed up Scala versions

Comment: Actually I submit my code straight from Eclipse. Can you please suggest how I need to modify my POM file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same version of Scala. Note that you are using Scala 2.11 everywhere except for Spark core:

```
spark-core_2.10
```

needs to be

```
spark-core_2.11
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! Your suggestion worked like a champ!! Thanks again!